# IComparer implementation when ordering by two parameters

Tags: c#, sorting, ienumerable

I am trying to sort an `IEnumerable<string>` and return a list with the following C# code:

```
IEnumerable<string> dirs = null;

dirs = (from file in (dir.EnumerateFiles("*.*", so)
                         .Where(file => reSearchPattern.IsMatch(Path.GetExtension(file.Name))))
        orderby file.Directory ascending, file.LastWriteTime ascending  
        select file.FullName);

return dirs.ToList()
```

But I get an error

> At least one object must implement IComparable

What do I do fix this?

Comment: `Directory.EnumerateFiles` returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, so your `file` in the LINQ query is a string. Calling `string.Directory` in your `orderby` has probably confused the parser

Comment: Changing 'order by file.Directory' to 'order by file.Directory.Fullname' fixes the problem